# Getting Unsupported java error on NiFi bootstrap.conf file

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, apache-nifi

I'm trying to install NiFi on a VitrualBox following:
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/8422/visualize-near-real-time-stock-price-changes-using.html

When I run "/op/nifi-1.0.0/bin/nifi.sh start" I get an error from the bootstrap.comf file: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Nifi release 1.0.0 depends on Java 8.

Meanwhile the `HDP Sandbox` image seems to bundle an earlier version of Java, so you will need to update the image or update the version of java in the image you have.